# load JavaScript function return value to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to javascript programming, can someone help me in achieving my need.   I need to assign the return value to a variable on calling this javascript file, this should be done inside a javascript file. I am not sure even my code is correct.

```
(function() {

return {
    css: [
        { file: 'css/theme-default.css' }
    ],
    js: [
        { file: 'config.js' }
    ],
    placeHolder: {
        content: {
            version: '2.0',
            developer: 'Sibiraj'
        },
        sitelogo: {
            visible: true,
            content: {
                title: 'Home'
            }
        },
    },
    bodyClass: 'default-v_3.0'
};
});
```

Comment: `var mVarName = myFuncName();` ?

Comment: I want something like var myjs = 'themes/config/js'

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do with the object shown

Comment: I don't want to load this file until required. not during page load

Comment: I don't have huge idea about [require js](http://requirejs.org/). But I think it will help you

Comment: Hmm, do you mean you want to send a file containing this data to your page after it has loaded? Have a look at basic ajax functions, those will allow you to fetch that js file, or even better, a json file. Also have a look at the documentation for angular. You might be able to put it into scope there somewhere as a static external asset. But I would advice to read a few more tutorials, sicne the exact syntax of `var myjs = 'themes/config/js'` is not going to work unless you feed that string into some function that fetches the data.

Comment: Okay @Shilly, I will check it out.

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar, Actually I am migrating from requirejs, Requirejs make things quite simpler, but I am unable to use pagespeed components So that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new function and call this function on [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function as below snippet

```js
$(function(){
   var data=Getdata();
})
 

function Getdata()
{
return {
    css: [
        { file: 'css/theme-default.css' }
    ],
    js: [
        { file: 'config.js' }
    ],
    placeHolder: {
        content: {
            version: '2.0',
            developer: 'Sibiraj'
        },
        sitelogo: {
            visible: true,
            content: {
                title: 'Home'
            }
        },
    },
    bodyClass: 'default-v_3.0'
};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do like this
var myjs = 'themes/config/js'.  so myjs has the return value

Comment: in this example you want `config.js` in `js` array right?